# How to write a table output with column names in SQL in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I use pandas library to write data which I retrieve from sql table. It is working but I don't see a column names there. Also each row is appended in Excel like

```
('aa','aa','01/10/2019','zzz')
('bb','cc','03/10/2019','yy')
..
```

I want my Excel sheet with column names and without colon.(') A proper excel sheet.

eg:

```
Name  Address   Date       product
 aa    aa      01/10/2019   zzz
```

My code is as follows;

```
cursor.execute(sql, values)
records = cursor.fetchall()

data = []
for row in records:
    data.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Invoice') 
writer.save()
```

How can I retrieve with column names and write that in excel using pandas?

I use pyodbc to connect to the SQL Server database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using pandas' built in [read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) function to read from your sql database.
This should read your header in properly and the datatypes too!

You'll need to define a sqlAlchemy connection to pass to pd.read_sql but that is simple for mssql:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mssql://timmy:tiger@localhost:5432/mydatabase')
connection = engine.connect()
query = "SELECT * FROM mytable"

df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
```

EDIT:
As per Ratha's comment, it should be noted that the sqlAlchemy connection isn't essential for read_sql to work, and indeed, from the docs a connection is defined as:

> con : SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI
>   or DBAPI2 connection (fallback mode)
>
> Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB supported by that library. If a DBAPI2 object, only sqlite3 is supported.

Comment: It is not necessary to have sqlalchemy connection string. I used pyodbc and working fine .Thanks

Comment: do you know how can I achieve this with read_sql?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59149457/does-pandas-support-reading-data-from-multiple-tables-into-a-dataframe